# Exporting large data in csv for users

Tags: export-to-csv

I am trying to make a system where users are allowed to export data in csv format. It is no problem in formatting the data in csv format. I am having he problem in processing the request for csv export data. suppose a User requests for exporting all data and it is huge. I think it would not be best way to ask user to wait untill the request is complete right? Should I tell users that exporting of data is in progress and we will notify once it is complete? If yes i should use background process for it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with streaming data to users in csv format using nodejs.

```
function csvExport(req, res){
   mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=connects.csv');
        res.header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

        var csv_header_row = "Email,First Name,Last Name,Status,Created\n";
        res.write(csv_header_row);
        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM contacts where user_id = ? AND deleted = 0', [req.params.user_id]);
            query
            .on('error', function(err) {
                //handle error
            })
            .on('fields', function(fields) {

            })
            .on('result', function(row) {
                var csv_row = row.email+','+row.first_name+','+row.last_name+','+row.status+','+row.created+"\n";
                res.write(csv_row);
            })
            .on('end', function() {
                res.end('', function(){
                    console.log('done');
                });
            });
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, define some kind of configurable 'setting' which might default to 10Mb.  If you can tell the export will be more than 10Mb you ask the user if they want to export such a large rowset.  If possible, estimate the size and let them know how large that will be. If you show them a progress bar while you're running a background export you'll have to have some sort of process to process communication to pass that back to the user command form.  Have an option on the form to change that setting to a number closer to the one they want as a warning level.